# Can I craft Spikes and other fist weapons for a Monk?

Tags: diablo-iii

My blacksmith is at Level 3 (Adept) and I don't see fist weapons that I can craft.

Will be able to craft any fist weapons later? If so, what are the requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can craft fist weapons later, just continue upgrading your blacksmith. In fact the first fist weapon is available from level 3 - which is what you have - so you're only a few upgrades away from it (remember each level has multiple inner sublevels, each unlocking its own recipes).

[Here is a full list of all craftable fist weapons](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/fist-weapon/#type=crafted) along with their level requirement, blacksmith's level requirement, and component list. To summarize the level requirements:

```
Name                         Character level   Blacksmith level
Adept Shuko                  24                 3
Grand Master Knuckles        35                 5
Demon Hand                   52                 7
Resplended Demon Fang        59                 8
Hallowed Touch               60                 4 (requires plan)
Exalted Fine Golden Talon    60                10 (requires plan)
Exalted Golden Talon         60                10 (requires plan)
Exalted Grand Golden Talon   60                10 (requires plan)
```

Comment: They got that from the strategy guide, what he's not telling you is you can only upgrade to a specific level but then eventually you have to start getting something of blacksmithing i'm sorry i can not remember the name that comes before that, i believe its called scroll of blacksmithing

Comment: @dennis How do you mean? Do I need to get another item or something?

Comment: thanks - what does `(requires plan)` mean - advanced character planning to unlock that?

Comment: @Sathya You need to collect plans and teach them to the Blacksmith in order to craft certain things.

Comment: @Sathya plans are simply items that drop and are required for crafting the item. Unlike other crafting components, plans are only used for one specific crafted item. [Here's a list of all the plans and their levels](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/).

Comment: @Sathya Dennis means that in order to upgrade/train your blacksmith past level 4 you'll start needing to collect Pages of Blacksmith, which only start appearing on Nightmare difficulty as far as I'm aware(although you can buy them from the auction house).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to acquire Plans to build more advanced items. The plans are just like molds you find in other games or a item required to make a specific weapon/piece of armor, (which they left out there is legendary armorsets that require molds to create along with a mold required to make the weapon for a complete set bonus)).

I have not found any yet but I know they are out there. You don't start getting the  blacksmith scrolls until nightmare difficulty, you may be able to get it in normal, I did not though.