# Does the blacksmith craft monk-specific gear?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

In leveling up the blacksmith, he will definitely craft some gear that is of no use to the monk (for example, a two-handed sword).  Does he eventually craft gear that is monk-specific?  Is it worth leveling the blacksmith to the point where such gear becomes available?

Comment: [Can I craft Spikes and other fist weapons for a Monk?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/68141)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he does craft monk-specific gear

You can start crafting a [Daibo at Level 2](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/progression/#level=2) (2H Monk weapon), and Monk fist weapons at [60% of Level 3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/progression/#level=3)

Currently, the blacksmith is just a big money sink where you can spend materials and money for a chance at some great items, but it is often better to take that money and buy a good item from the AH.

Still, it's nice for keeping your armor up-to-date while you level, and saves you the time and hassle of searching the AH for items :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the Blacksmith's progression](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/progression/#level=3), it seems at the end of Level 3 he gains the ability to create an [Adept Shuko](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/adept-shuko).  So, yes, the blacksmith can eventually craft Monk-specific gear.

Currently, though, it's not worth the effort to level him up; the auction house provides items at a much better price-point.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree, once you level the blacksmith up he can be used for all your characters. This alone makes it very advantageous to train the blacksmith to level 3 or 4

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.